# what is a QR code used when applying for or receiving a ETA for India

Tags: eta

Have obtained a ETA for India but there is no photograph.  Is it o.k. to just print off the ETA and carry it with me?  What is a QR code?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code for a full description of QR codes

Comment: Go to Indian eVisa website and get from there your eVisa. I think you already understood that Indian eVisa website is not intuitive (or worse). I do not understand why they send a PDF about visa information but not the eVISA.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi they do that because the actual visa is put into the passport by the immigration officer when you enter India for the first time.

Comment: @phoog: it was not my comment: there is one PDF with almost all information send to email, and a second PDF with also the photo on the website, AFAIK no direct link. They requires this second document to be able to have the stamp on the printed PDF and on passport The printed document with stamp should be carried. Ah, and that printed PDF (with photo) is checked 3 times in three different step/places before really entering in India.

Answer (score 1):

This [forum post](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/permalink/post/22970196) details what's going on:

> I had already checked the status on the [website](https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/evisa/StatusEnquiry), but the query returned the exact same text-only reply from my email. There is a "PRINT" button at the bottom that I assumed (assuming was my error) that this would just print out this text. However, when I hit PRINT, it actually brought up the full PDF of the visa with the barcodes and the photo.

(Note the original post didn't link "website", I did, using the URL from a previous post in the same thread.)

And note another post in the same thread:

> you need to bring the hardcopy with you to immigration. You'll be photographed, finger-printed and the visa stamped into your passport.